# Influx + Grafana aggregate / add 2 sets of data?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

Is it possible to form a query that will add the results of these 2 queries together?

`SELECT "output1" FROM "output1"`

`SELECT "output2" FROM "output2"`

It is to display a Singlestat value in Grafana.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to join data across two measurements.

As a work around you could use a continuos query to write data into the same measurement like so

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY join_output1_output2 ON mydb BEGIN
  SELECT "output2" INTO "output1" FROM "output2"
END
```

Then the query

```
SELECT "output1" + "output2" FROM "output1"
```

Comment: I have a series of measurements that include a value, average, and dispersion. I wanted to show where the value exceeds "mean +/- factor * dispersion", but that seems not possible. Kind of a negative surprise.